# Number of ways to write a number as a sum of powers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

Lets denote $\mathcal N_{k,n}$ the function that return the number of ways to write a given number as sum of $k$ numbers to the $n$-th power.

For example :
$\mathcal N_{3,2}(1)=3$ because 
\begin{align*}
1
&=1^2+0^2+0^2 \\ &=0^2+1^2+0^2 \\ &=0^2+0^2+1^2 \\&=(-1)^2+0^2+0^2 \\ &=0^2+(-1)^2+0^2 \\ &=0^2+0^2+(-1)^2.
\end{align*}

We already now that

$$\forall n\in\mathbb N \quad \mathcal N_{4,2}=\sum_{d\mid n \text{ and } 4\nmid d}d.$$

Is there a more general formula for most $k$ and $n$ ?

Is there at least other formulas like that for some non trivial $k$ and $n$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are more formulas for squares, see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html).
Two more examples for the sum of squares are given by
$$
\mathcal{N}_{6}(n)=16\sum_{d\mid n}\chi (\frac{n}{d})d^2-4\sum_{d\mid n}\chi(d) d^2,
$$

with $\chi$ a character modulo $4$ and

$$
\mathcal{N}_{8}(n)=6\sum_{d\mid n}(-1)^{n+d}d^3.
$$
For higher degree, there are also results, in connection with Waring's problem, starting with an integral for $\mathcal{N}_{k,n}$ by Hardy and Littlewood.